How to assign a variable to a true value of an if statement
I am creating a tool to automatically fill out web forms across many websites. My current code to find the entry fields is:
try:
  Select_Box_Name = (driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'your-name')
  Select_Box_Name.click()
  time.sleep(1)
  Select_Box_Name.send_keys(FullName)
except: 
  print("Invalid")

This works for a single website, but, since different websites use different labels/names/etc., I need to have "Select_Box_Name.send_keys(FullName)" be applied to all the different possibilities.
The solution I initially thought of is using an if statement to check if a field is present/true. Here is the code I have so far:
if driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'your-name') or driver.find_element(by.NAME, 'full-name'):
  print("Found")

What I want to do is to assign the "Select_Box_Name" variable to whatever the truthy value of the if statement is. Is this possible or is there an alternative method I can apply? Thanks!

to see if you found an element use find_elements... if the array returned has a size of zero, then it was not found.  Depending on the site, you may want a sleep first, or a webdriverwait...

You can assign the value of Select_Box_Name to the expression in the if statement
Select_Box_Name = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'your-name') or driver.find_element(by.NAME, 'full-name'
and then do
if Select_Box_name: print("Found")

So I implemented this and it seems to only be reading the first option for the variable (in this example, reading 'your-name'). If the correct name is 'full-name', then it is returning invalid.
